# Cannot install Ubuntu after creating a 5th partition in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10, grubrescue

I had a Windows / Kubuntu dual boot. In Windows I added a new partition, however I had 4 partitions already. Therefore I think Windows changed all of my partitions' file systems to NTFS. Then all of the partitions appeared in "This PC".

Up to that time I had not understood what Windows did with my partitions. I thought that I probably created two partitions instead of one, so I formatted them as Windows prompted. When I restarted my computer I got into rescue mode with a `No such partition` error. I repaired Windows with a disk installer. Unfortunately now I cannot install Ubuntu.

I have one partition which was ntfs before this mess, where all of my important files are located. I have access to it, and I'm sure it's safe.
I want to install Ubuntu, but keep that partition.

[image]

In the above screenshot, sdbs and sdc are two USB drives. I cannot resolve where my above-mentioned partition went. I can delete and I resized the sda4 partition in KDE Partition Manager, but when I try to install Ubuntu there I get `The ext4 partition creation in sda4 failed`. After that a window with following message appears:

> ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do not, your installation may fail entirely or may be broken.

Comment: Perhaps Windows changed your partitions to "dynamic" from simple when you made that 5th partition?  Ubuntu cannot use dynamic partitions, they are Microsoft proprietary.  If you are limited to 4 primary partitions, make one an extended partition, then add the Ubuntu parttiions inside the extended as "logical" partitions.

Comment: Instructions for doing what ubfan1 suggested in the previous comment + screenshots are in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279822/).