# Unable to install ubuntu alonside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bios, usb-installation

So, basically the situation is that I am trying to dual-boot ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS with windows 10.

In System Information of windows, the `BIOS mode is Legacy`.

Now, I created a bootable Usb using rufus and with default options of **MBR and BIOS(or UEFI-CSM)** as suggested in official tutorial.

But when I put the usb in and booted the system, by default it simply boots to windows.
I had to press F12 to get the list of boot options.
The options were like this

```
BIOS boot mode is Legacy, Secure Boot Off

Legacy-
 Hard Drive
 Usb Storage Device
 Network

UEFI
 Sandisk Usb.. // basically the name of that usb

... //other options
```

1. Now, if i choose the option in UEFI it doesn't recognises windows at all and offers the option to only install ubuntu (cleaning all the disks)
2. Next time, I chose the `Usb Storage Device` under legacy and [here (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKoL7.jpg) it recognised windows 10 but again doesn't gives the alongside install options as seen in online tutorials. Why?

And, I clicked something else in this case and it opened up the partion manager but I didn't edited anything as it was too complicated. Now, on booting windows - the screen was blank after login and I had to restart it to restore normal work.

So, what is going wrong and how to correct it.

**P.S.** As commented below, I have 4 primary partitions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wu1i.jpg). But will fulfilling this criteria of less than 4 partitions, will the above issues be solved. Also, any logic why my screen was going blank (except cursor) after login.

Comment: Do you have another partition on your disk on which Ubuntu could be installed? To my knowledge, the installer only offers an option to install Ubuntu alongside already existing OS (be it Windows or another Ubuntu installation) if it finds a partition where it can install the system.

Comment: i don't have one but can easily make with partion manager, but I have seen on youtube that the installer itself gives the option to create partition and also a slider for adjusting storage

Comment: Make sure Windows fast start up is off. If Windows is the old BIOS/MBR configuration, have you used all 4 primary partitions? Post this from live installer: `sudo fdisk -lu`. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode since 2012, so most hardware is now UEFI. But you cannot easily convert Windows BIOS boot as it requires the old MBR partitioning to UEFI boot as that requires gpt partitioning & conversion of partitioning normally erases drive. Be sure to have good backups.

Comment: @raj you are wrong. Ubuntu does not need "another partition" it needs unallocated space in the drive to create the partition(s) it needs. Most likely reason here is the drive already have 4 primary partitions, the maximum allowed under MBR, which is usually used with legacy BIOS. Alternately, fast boot is turned on in Windows 10, and Ubuntu installer cannot shrink the Windows partition to make the unallocated space it needs.

Comment: what do i do now?

Comment: @user68186 one thing to say is that I didn't changed the boot order in the setup, I simply clicked on the above sandisk or usb options

Comment: @user68186 yes, i have 4 primary partitions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wu1i.jpg). Then, what's the solution as all the 2 drives other than C and system reserve are very dear to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: If you have enough space in D: to put all the files and folders in E: in D: or vice versa, then do it. Once one of the partition is empty, then delete the empty partition from within Windows. Then run the Ubuntu installer again. Before you do any of these, go out and buy an external hard drive to copy all the contents (data, personal files, music, videos, everything) from C, D, and E to the external hard drive.

Comment: @user68186 attempted an install. see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317835/ended-up-with-5-primary-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu-ubuntu-still-nowhere)