# How do I keep unallocated space as free space in the dual logging setup process? instead my partition turns to unusable disk

Tags: gparted

I am setting up dual logging and used the link at the bottom of this question as a guide. Under the Getting Windows Heading (screenshot/image #6) it goes about how to make unallocated space. I did shrink 64GB of space and it appears just like the screenshot in this link. Scroll down several pages to get to around image 16-17ish and this is where I am not seeing the partition made earlier available as free space. It says Unusable.

Somewhere I saw a thread about turning off BitLocker and I have. Now I have made several attempts restarting  again and verifying every step.  Around image 20-ish the author says that you can do the partitioning here instead but recommends doing it in the native Windows software for a risk-free process. I have tried it several ways without going to far and erasing anything to no avail. I saw somewhere a tip about making a logical drive instead of shrinking the volume. I have not found any guide for this process and doesn't appear intuitively when I keep attempting. This is so I can run Linux and Windows from same rig. The promised link is below:

https://medium.com/linuxforeveryone/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-and-dual-boot-alongside-windows-10-323a85271a73

Image below, Windows partitions.  Then in Ubuntu Installer, free space listed at the top but listed as unusable below.  I have read about GParted, but I'm not sure if partition table is the answer or not.

Partitions in Windows Disk Management:

[image: partitions in Windows]]

*Installation type* screen in Ubuntu Installer:

[image: In Ubuntu Installer]

Comment: How many partitions do you have (excluding the unallocated space that isn't a partition)?

Comment: "Try Ubuntu" from the USB and open the "Disks" application. Do you see your unpartitioned space there?

Comment: I am running late for certification class but I will get screenshots added (edited in) to clear up some things after class tonight.  I do not why there are 4 partitions already.  There is System, Windows C:, and 2 Healthy (Recovery Partitions).  I will need to make a SWAP partition as well so I need to change one of the Health partitions into free space as well I think

Comment: No, you do not need a swap partition. Ubuntu will use a swap file in absence of a swap partition.  If you have a decent amount of RAM, swap will rarely be used, if ever. A typical Windows installation will have several partitions as well as your EFI partition. Leave those alone or you risk breaking your Windows installation.

Comment: I have 8GB RAM so I should be ok I guess, thanks for the tips

Comment: Your disk does not have GPT but old msdos partition table, thus limited to four primary partitions.

Comment: @Nmath I don't see any EFI System Partition (ESP) in either pictures. This makes me think this disk is initialized as MBR, not GPT and has 4 primary partitions, the maximum number possible. The only solution is to delete one of the recovery or backup partitions.

Comment: I think it is initialized as MBR.  Take a look at the image of the partitioning.  One of the 4 partitions is the one I created for an Ubuntu partition.  The number of partitions is not the issue if the SWAP is not an issue like mentioned above.  The issue is the partition is not being recognized as free space in the Ubuntu installer, it is listed as free space at the top on the bar but down in the list it is "unusable"

Comment: I am getting a newer laptop tomorrow.  I appreciate everyone's input.  I learned a bunch. I discovered that this 2016 refurbished (I'm a poor student) rig is pretty solid for a year now but has legacy motherboard.  If the motherboard is too old it is not setup for EFI/UEFI.

Comment: Are you sure about that? A laptop from 2016 should support UEFI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: *"One of the 4 partitions is the one I created for an Ubuntu partition."* This is incorrect. The 4 primary partitions in the first picture are labeled as **1.** System, **2.** Windows (C:), **3.** 591 MB Healthy (Recovery Partition) **4.** 500 MB Healthy (Recovery Partition). In the **second picture** these are referred to as **1.** `/dev/sda1`,  **2.** `/dev/sda2`,  **3.** `/dev/sda3`,  **4.** `/dev/sda4`. This is why the free (unallocated) space you created by shrinking "C:" is unusable. Delete **3.** 591 MB Healthy (Recovery Partition) AKA `/dev/sda3` and start the installation again.

Comment: Sorry I had thought I attached a different image that shows a 5th partition.  The refurbisher I bought it from could not get it to format UEFI and said that happens often and most of their clients needs' are met with BIOS.

Comment: He could not do anything for that rig but I got another newer laptop configed for UEFI and he threw in extra memory stick to double the RAM to 16GB.  I am making a bootable USB for Windows 10 on new computer right now.  Going to then make the partition for Ubuntu.  I read that I should make the partition in Windows environment instead of when I am in the Installer from the Ubuntu stick, as Ubuntu may delete part of C: drive.  When I make this Windows stick I read I should format it exFat32 not NTFS?

Comment: In Windows shrink an existing partition. Leave the space Unallocated. The Ubuntu installer will find it and offer to install in the unallocated space if you select **Install Ubuntu side by side with Windows** option. Ubuntu users format ext4, Windows can't create or use this format.