# No HDD shows up during install 12.04 on Lenovo U410

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo U410 laptop. When I launch installation no partitions shows up.

The U410 has 2 HDDs. 32 GB SSD on /dev/sda and a 500 HDD on /dev/sdb

Ideally I would like to install Ubuntu on the 32GB SSD and keep Windows on the 500 GB one and not use the Intel Smart Response Technolog. I'm ok with flashing my drive and starting from scratch with this.

Or do you'll have any better suggestions on how to go about partitioning my drive and how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same Problem. Because I uninstall the dmraid package during the installation within the Ubuntu-Live-System i could see both disks and install Ubuntu. But this breaks the RAID0 and the ntfs file system got damaged. So I flashed the disk and started from the scratch.

In my View you have 2 Options, beside the one you described:

1. Deactivate the Intel Smart Response Technology within Windows using the GUI, change the SATA mode in the BIOS from RAID to normal. Then your Ubuntu installer should recognize both disks.
   (But beware, I don't know how Windows or rather ntfs behaves if you deactivate the RAID mode. Your ntfs filesystem could also get damaged)
2. I investigated a little this special RAID0 (stripping) mode. In the Ubuntu-Live-System it should be able to address the RAID using the dmraid or the mdadm package (Without breaking the RAID).
   http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/cs-020663.htm 
   Theoretically it should be possible to install Ubuntu on the SSD. Implied the Intel Rapid Storage Technology is configured with just 18,6GB of the 32GB SSD (Intel RST can be used with at least 18,6GB and at most 64GB). I don't know with how much space the Intel RST is configured out of the box after the purchase

Soon I will try Option 2 myself. I flashed the whole system, installed Windows and configured the Intel Rapid Storage Technology with just 18,6GB.