# installing 64bit 12.04 LTS along with 32bit window 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I am facing issues with installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64 bits) alongside Windows 7 (32 bits).

My machine is Intel i5. My current Windows partitions are:

- `C:` Drive of 50 GB
- `D:` Drive of 195 GB
- `E:` Drive of 221 GB
- `System Reserved` of 100 MB.

I tried to USB boot and install Ubuntu, during the installing process I could see 3 options:

**a)** install inside Windows 7 **b)** Erase **c)** Something else.

I choose "something else" and when proceeded, I could't find all my Windows partitions.

Given below is my `fdisk -l` report:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3e025634

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
/dev/sda2   *        2048      206847      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3          206848   102402047    51097600   42  SFS
/dev/sda4       102402048   976771119   437184536   42  SFS

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32015679488 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62530624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4da96a7f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32    62530623    31265296    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

listing below is my parted -l command report.

Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54505 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB  primary  ext2
 2      1049kB  106MB   105MB   primary  ntfs         boot
 3      106MB   52.4GB  52.3GB  primary  ntfs
 4      52.4GB  500GB   448GB   primary  ntfs

Model: SanDisk Cruzer Force (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      16.4kB  32.0GB  32.0GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba

I also tried to execute the command "sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda". for which i got error message like "no raid disks and with names: "/dev/sda".

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 64 bits, when you choose "something else" option, you have to be sure that you have enough free space for two aditional partitions one ext4 partition and the swap partition, windows partitions look like dev/sdb 3 140 GB ntfs and dev/sdb 2 100 MB ntfs.

Comment: why under System it is showing SFS, in other examples (http://askubuntu.com/questions/191511/ubuntu-installer-does-not-show-drives?rq=1) it is able to detect the windows partition. and displayed as NTFS etc. Earlier i have kept 10 GB freespace but ubuntu installer could't identify that free space. so i added that into my E: drive.

Answer (score 0):

Installing "64-Bit OS on a 32-Bit Computer" / "32-Bit OS on a 64-Bit Computer", might create a lot of problems. 32-Bit Computer may not be able to handle a 64-Bit OS, or the vice versa.
So, download and install "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin (32-Bit)"

Comment: My machine is intel i5 which means its, 64bit machine.