# Can't find 2nd hard drive in ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

My computer has 2 drives, an 30 GB SSD with Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it, and a second 500 GB HDD for storage. I've checked all my BIOS settings, and searched through Ubuntu, and I can't figure out how to access my HDD on Ubuntu.

Comment: can you see it in Disk Utility?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/164980/no-hdd-shows-up-during-install-12-04-on-lenovo-u410

Comment: What filesystem type is the drive formatted to?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you cannot access the secondary, 500GB drive.

Open a terminal emulator and verify that the disk is recognized by the kernel:

```
egrep 'sd[a-z]' /proc/partitions
```

You'll probably see sda[0-9] and the second disk should usually be detected as sdb, but that depends on what other usb-storage devices are connected.

If the above command shows anything other that sda[0-9], try this

```
blkid | egrep 'sd[a-z]'
```

This will print a list of disks and/or partitions (depending on how your disks are configured) their UUIDs, file system types and labels (if applicable).

If you need more help, please paste output from those commands.