# Clarification: SSD Cache Hard Drive w/ intel raid

Tags: lenovo, ssd

I am considering the Lenovo U410.

From everything I have read [[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164980/no-hdd-shows-up-during-install-12-04-on-lenovo-u410), [2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2023374), [3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DGRVHJFvIo), [4](http://www.melaneum.com/blog/linux/installing-ubuntu-on-a-lenovo-u410), [5](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1184106)], It seems that Ubuntu can be best installed by turning off the RAID0 configuration and doing a wipe. I have no interest in keeping Windows, but I want to confirm something that remains unclear to me.

Once I have disabled RAID, will I be able to access the SS Cache and the HDD individually as one would expect? My ideal configuration would be to have root (/) mounted on the SSD, and /home mounted to the HDD. Is that straightforward once RAID is disabled? Would I get the performance boost I expect from a SSD?

Finally, are there any other factors to consider relating to compatibility?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My understanding is once you disable RAID0 you should be able to mount `/` on the SSD and `/home` on the HHD. You may also put `/home` in the SSD (in a separate partition if you want) and sym link *Documents, Pictures, Music, Video* etc. to the HDD. This way your personal config files and folders for applications reside in the SSD and the applications load faster. However, since I have not tried it out, I can't be sure and thus the comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did buy the Lenovo U410, and there was relatively little effort in installing Ubuntu onto it.

The BIOS was a bit of a pain to get into because it goes through the startup so quickly, and the BIOS treats the function keys as media keys (which can be disabled in the BIOS, once you get in).

Once into the BIOS, setting the controller to AHCI allows the Ubuntu installer to see the SSD and HDD as separate devices, and you can partition and install accordingly.

I partitioned the SDD for / and /home, and if I start keeping massive files on the computer, I'll just simlink (or mount) folders in my home directory to directories (or partitions) on the HDD. No problems.

Everything else seems to work well, after about 3 months of use. The trackpad is a little irritating, and I don't have any multitouch features working, but I'm sure that can be fixed with configuration.

Answer (score 0):

What I did with my u410 was put the sata controller into AHCI mode (enable legace mode booting, and enable USB Legacy mode), and then installed ubuntu to the mechanical disk (I used a single partition, but there's no reason you couldn't use a separate one for your /home as well). From there I used flashcache (step by step directions located [here](http://nitocris.over-blog.net/article-flash-cache-as-home-or-root-on-ubuntu-109792445.html)) and now I find that booting and what not happens just about as quickly as it does right off the SSD. I would have preferred to use bcache, but couldn't be bothered to pave that road with ubuntu.