# Ubuntu 12.04.3 installer UEFI not recognizing Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

As stated in the title, Ubuntu installer does not recognize Windows 8 and it will not offer the "Install along with Windows" option. Only "Erase everything" or "Something else". How can I solve this?

Important details:

1. My  disk is GPT.
2. I can see and browse Windows partitions (`OS` (`C:`), `System`, recovery etc.) just fine from Nautilus while in Live. I didn't have to mount them manually or anything similar. I can even write and read files.
3. GParted will recognize all partitions correctly
4. No error is reported in `boot.log` and the disk is correctly mounted (i.e. nothing special in `dmesg`).
5. I have Secure Boot enabled. I tried with SB disabled and nothing changed.
6. I have already resized Windows partition from Windows Disk Manager and created enough free space for Ubuntu to install (15GB)
7. I am pretty confident that the USB key I use for booting Ubuntu is OK: the md5sum of the ISO was ok, I created the USB disk with `ddrescue` and `sync`ed it before unplugging.
8. If I choose "Something else" from the installer, no partition is reported in the hard disk (so I cannot even do it manually and I don't want to risk blindly erasing the disk).
9. Reinstalling Windows 8 is not an option.
10. I would like to avoid DIY scripts and tools: I am not asking for anything special, Ubuntu installer should work the usual way. If some command-line-fu is needed, please include the relevant commands in the answer.
11. The Live disk boots ok, and everything works as expected (I can install programs, browse the Internet with Firefox etc.).
12. I am booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: Have you had a look at [**How to install linux on a computer with GPT?**](http://askubuntu.com/a/244334/179042)

Comment: Yes. My disk is GPT, I am sure. I have double checked, no leftover data, plus I already have 7 partions (no logic), which wouldn't be possible if the disk was actually MBR. Additionally, I never installed Windows 7 or previous.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. Use the "Something Else" option. Although it references Windows 7, [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else) should help.

Answer (score 0):

Please boot Windows 8 and disable Secure Boot and Quick Boot.
http://www.typicaltips.com/2013/02/disable-fast-startup-in-windows-8.html

Then try again with Ubuntu 12.04.3 or better yet, wait until tomorrow to download Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Answer (score 0):

try boot-repair from live-usb. you can read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

hope it will solve your problem, because i also use boot-repair to make grub recognize windows 8 and ubuntu itself