# I Can't Install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi, windows-7, 13.04

I download ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso and write on a DVD then check it with a MD5 checker and it's OK.
I decide to Install Ubuntu on my PC that have Windows 7 sp1 64-bit simultaneously.
I follow [this manual](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) from Ubuntu website.

In step 4 when I choose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" and click continue my screen turn black and DVD would be ejected and When I press Enter the system would be restarted.

Also in windows I can't use wubi, When I Run wubi with administrator permission it show nothing, I try wubi.exe --force-wubi and did nothing.

I have this problem with Ubuntu 12.04.2.

[My Laptop specification](http://uk.asus.com/Notebooks/Multimedia_Entertainment/N53SV/):

ASUS N53SV

CPU: Intel Corei7 2630QM

RAM: 4.00 GB

Graphic Card: Nvidia Geforce GT 540M & Intel HD Graphic Family

Comment: Is it 12.04 or 13.04?

Comment: Please edit your question adding your computer brand,model, graphics card, wireless etc. Thanks. Also check the `%TEMP%` directory for the Wubi log.

Comment: @Alex I have same problem with Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04

Comment: @bcbc I just edit question with my laptop specifications

Comment: @Ehsan I can't see anything related to that model. Are you sure it says "Alongside" and not "Inside" (which happens if you have 4 primary partitions)? If you instead select *Try Ubuntu* (without installing), does it boot to the desktop fine?. If so, you can run the [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) and post a link to that.

Comment: @bcbc yes when I try Ubuntu, It's good, I could to run wubi but I want to Install from Boot

Comment: @Ehsan okay well check the partitions then, because it sounds like it could be this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69481/why-dont-i-have-the-option-install-ubuntu-alongside-with-them/272036#272036

Comment: I find that what is the problem, I have 4 partition. My question now is How I can create 5th partition without lose any data, I ask here: http://superuser.com/questions/589039/create-5th-partiotion-with-gparted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I had 4 primary drives in my hard disk, and MBR can't add a new drive letter for Ubuntu so accrue an error and restart my computer. But I expected to Ubuntu display related error.

I delete two primary drive first and then install Ubuntu without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

- Why you want to install alongside of Windows? Try something else. Choose another partition that didn't effect your Windows files.
- 2nd way: Boot live DVD without restricted VGA driver. You can
     find it when boot menu appear.

Comment: Hi Amin, I found my problem I have 4 primary partition and I can't create new partition

Comment: ok! so you must delete a 2 partitions at least to create a sub partitions!

Comment: Can linux partitions be logical?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/589039/create-5th-partiotion-with-gparted

Comment: Since you already have 4 primary partitions, you need to delete a primary partition and replace it with an extended partition in order to create new logical partitions.