# Ubuntu 13.04 install along windows 8 fails

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, 13.04, windows-8

I have a MSI FX-600 laptop with core-i3 330M, 4 GB RAM, 500 GB Hard Disk. My laptop comes with windows 7 pre-installed. I have upgraded it to Windows 8 recently. As it is with windows 7 pre-installed not Windows 8, I am quite sure UEFI is not an issue here.

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 AMD64 iso & created live USB using universal Linux installer. Then I booted my PC from USB and choose Install Ubuntu/Install inside Windows 8[?]. Then the computer restarts instantly and starts Ubuntu installation from scratch if pendrive is connected, and Windows 8 if pendrive is not connected. I searched over the forum & found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287642/i-cant-install-ubuntu-13-04-alongside-windows-7). This states that more than 4 primary partition can't be created. But I personally created only 2 partitions & don't intend to reduce further. My partition table using Windows disk manager is as follows.[My partition table](http://i44.tinypic.com/72wo3l.jpg).

Here the 12 GB partition is the recovery partition & I don't think it makes sense to remove that. I intend to use some space from 393 GB partition and install Ubuntu there. Please provide me with step by step instruction to do so.

[?] Why does it state install inside inside Windows, when I intend to install alongside? I took that as a typo.

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/72wo3l.jpg]

Comment: IF you create a bootable usb stick with the live cd from the Ubuntu website. Just follow the instructions on the live CD. Try out Ubuntu before you install it.

Comment: I don't want to try out Ubuntu, I want to install it. I tried several versions of Ubuntu & if my University didn't force me with some Windows specific software, I would certainly have thrown it away.

Comment: PS you also have dynamic disks which aren't supported by linux e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-dynamic-disk-the-request-isnt-suppor

Comment: I removed windows permanently now and I am sorry about one thing only, the recovery partition.