# Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 Dual boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I already have Windows 10 installed on my laptop and am now trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside it. I've got a UEFI enabled bootable pen drive with Ubuntu 14.04 image on it. I've gone through numerous Q&A on web on this topic but I can't seem to find a working solution.

I've around 400GB of unalocated space as you can see here [image]

The problem occurs when I boot from the pen drive and I select the install Ubuntu option and after I reach the screen with the option **Something else**. First I notice that it says **no operating system detected**. Also after I check something else option it takes me to a screen which shows the partitions. Over there it displays free space around 1000000 MB(the entire hard drive). Which means it is not detecting the windows partitioning. Furthermore if I go ahead and create ext4 and swap partitions and click on install I end up replacing Windows with ubuntu 14.04.

Also why does it not give me the option to install ubuntu alongside windows(dual boot). Something else option is not working for me.
Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like the pen drive is booting Legacy not UEFI. look on the pendrive to see if there is a folder named EFI. if not you need a different ubuntu image.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: @ravery There certainly is a folder named EFI

Comment: I've also checked my boot priority.. it is set to UEFI first

Comment: check your system settings, turn off legacy support if you can and try again.

Comment: ok.. will try that

Comment: @ravery I tried switching boot mode from legacy support to UEFI.. On doing so it said insert recovery media and select boot option.. But the boot menu I get on hitting ok is completely empty.. Though I had my bootable pen drive inserted

Comment: secure boot has to be off. if it is then the image you have is not uefi.

Comment: I used etcher to create the UEFI enabled pen drive. Also as u suggested I had the EFI folder in the pen drive

Comment: I tried following this tutorial https://www.appgeeker.com/recovery/disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-10.html to turn off secure boot but After I go to Troubleshoot->advanced options I do not get the option UEFI Firmware settings. Can you suggest some other tutorial for windows 10

Comment: ok I tried the steps given in this tutorial http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/07/27/how-to-disable-secure-boot-on-a-lenovo-g50-laptop/ .. I turned off secure boot but it still say  insert recovery media and select boot option.. Also the boot menu I get on hitting ok is completely empty

Comment: the system settings are different for each computer. Secure boot setting should be near the boot settingss or in security, some will not let you turn off secure boot. no tutorial is needed to make a uefi boot drive if you have a uefi boot image. just burn it to disk. NOTE:uefi boot images for ubuntu are 64-bit only

Comment: a side note, see if windows will boot in uefi only mode. maybe we are going the wrong direction here.  win10 should be uefi, but you may have a bios install. did you upgrade from win7?

Comment: nope. I directly installed windows 10

Comment: @ravery I've checked I am using 64bit uefi image. Also I've tried turning off secure boot still no luck

Comment: Windows *can* boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Ubuntu *usually* works with Secure Boot enabled (but there are rare exceptions to this rule). You can tell whether you've booted in BIOS or in EFI mode by looking for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode; if not, you've booted in BIOS mode. You're most likely running into a damaged partition table, as in [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370667/empty-disk-when-trying-to-install-dual-boot-system) Please post a screen shot of the partitioning screen if you want more help.