# Whole hardisk showing to install ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I made a live cd and then booted from it to install ubuntu when I got to the "something else" option it was only showing "/dev/sda" my partitions were not showing please help me I want to install it on a specific partition.

Comment: Do you want to dual boot? Formatting the partition to ext, FAT, or another filesystem that linux can recognize might work

Comment: possible duplicated [Ubuntu does not offers me "install alongside Windows"](http://askubuntu.com/a/371812)