# Ubuntu 12.04.04 LTS installation doesn't work

Tags: wubi, system-installation

I have been using ubuntu on my laptop for a while now.

I tried to install ubuntu on my desktop (64bit) with a CD, my ubuntu install cd starts and i can use it.

When i arrive at the screen "Installation type The computer currently has Windows 7 on it. What do you like to do?", it says.

1. Install ubuntu INSIDE windows 7 ( what is strange because it was alongside in the versions before. )
2. Replace windows 7 with Ubuntu
3. Something else

So i want to install ubuntu next windows 7, when i click Install ubuntu INSIDE 
windows 7 it closes ubuntu and comes to the screen "please remove the disk, close the tray (if any).
My computer restarts and opens windows 7. The disk auto starts WUBI on the computer.
I come on a window that display's some text like this:

[image]

I click on Demo and full installation. After this window it says that i need to restart my computer.
I restarted and i come in the beginning of the process again (so back to step 1) It keeps doing this in a loop.

This is a repost of a closed-off post you can find it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301153/stuck-at-install-loop-selecting-install-ubuntu-inside-windows-how-to-get-out?rq=1)

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/69481/why-dont-i-have-the-option-install-ubuntu-alongside-with-them

Comment: I will look into it, and give you a answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! I had indeed 4 primaries. Thank you very much!

Comment: This post can be closed.