# How can I install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7?

Tags: system-installation

How can I install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, because the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 does not show me? I want to install the hard disk partitioning manually. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you check out http://askubuntu.com/q/69481/169736?

Answer (score 0):

- Make a new partition to install Ubuntu.
- Boot your machine with the DVD or flash drive that you has the Ubuntu on it.
- Chose your language if it isn't already in your native language.
- And click on install Ubuntu.

It is really simple!!

When asked of what type of installation, maybe it's better to chose the advanced (called "Something Else") option. This will let you chose the partition and where you want to put the bootloader.

The sda will be your first hard drive, sda1 the first partition on that hard drive.
Hope it helps!!

Here's a great how to: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)