# In the partitioning step, when selecting "installing alongside" I'm redirected to Windows

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

At first I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from the website. I have the iso format downloaded.
The next thing I did was to write it in a DVD. Then took it for the process of installation from boot CD.

It went well until the point of asking for installing alongside Windows. But after that option is clicked, rather than asking for partition space, I'm being redirected to Windows.

I need a dual boot whilst stuck with the installation process. Kindly  out.

Comment: Are you sure it says "install alongside" and not "inside"? Check this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/371812/169736

Comment: What version of Windows? Windows 8 is usually UEFI. And Windows 7 has used all 4 primary partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu