# wubi uninstallation 12.04.3

Tags: windows-7, wubi, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 from USB stick inside Windows 7 as it asked for three options

1. to install inside windows
2. to install as its primary OS
3. to do something else

I chose to install *inside windows 7*. Installation was complete but it doesn't show any partition or drive of Ubuntu in the C: drive of Windows 7. Even though I can see that my C: drive partition as being reduced to size as used by ubuntu now that i want to Uninstall. I can't because I can't see the ubuntu drive in the windows 7 and nor can i access the uninstaller. I have also tried to run the uninstaller which is available at the site but it does not do anything.

Please help how do I uninstall Ubuntu from the windows 7.

Comment: Go to Add and Remove software in Windows and remove Ubuntu.

Comment: There's no install "inside" Windows option when booting from USB. There's only install *alongside* Windows. You have set up a dual-boot system and not a Wubi-based one.

Comment: @muru yes there is - if you have 4 primary partitions. See http://askubuntu.com/a/272036/14916

Comment: @bcbc interesting. I have never seen that option even with four primary partitions.

Comment: no even in the control panel from where we uninstall programs in windows 7 doesn't show the ubuntu installed no entry can be seen.

Comment: Samuel, that option only copies wubi.exe to your Windows Startup folder. Did you reboot into Windows and complete the install (which would have downloaded the disk image (800MB)? You can't have missed it if it did... also there would be an `\ubuntu\ ` folder with a `disks\root.disk` file over 5GB. (If you installed)

Comment: @muru 4 primary partitions and also a Windows install on one of them ;)

Comment: @bcbc yes, Windows was present. I'm talking of the HP laptops which have a tendency to use all four primary partitions.